# Why is v[i] returning a length of 0 when my vector 'v' has a proper length?

Tags: r

I'm curious, why does length(v[i]) = 0?

my vector is called "v", it has a proper length, but v[i] has length 0.

I'm a new student, my homework is to create a vector with all multiples of 3 smaller than 100.

I was trying the following:

```
v <- 0
i <- 0
while(v[i] < 100) {
  i <- i + 1
  v[i] <- i*3
}
```

and i got "Error in while (v[i] < 100) { : argument is of length zero"
while testing, i saw that:
length(v) = 1
length(v[i]) = 0

i just dont know why.

obs: For now, the solution that i thought of was:

```
v <- 0
i <- 0
x <- 0
while(x < 100) {
  i <- i + 1
  v[i] <- i*3
  x[1] <- v[i]
  if(x > 100){
    v <- head(v,-1)
  }
};v
```

Comment: R uses one-based indexing. There is no element 0. So `v[1]` would exist but `v[0]` does not. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: To add to MrFlick, technically, `v[0]` returns the empty set `numeric(0)`, which is a numeric vector of length zero. That's where the error message comes from, the `while` statement sees a logical vector of length 0.